# Difference between std::move() and std::add_rvalue_reference()

Tags: c++, c++11

Can somebody explain the difference between `std::move()` and `std::add_rvalue_reference()`? Do both serve the same purpose? If yes, what is the advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::move` is a cast on an object, `std::add_rvalue_reference` manipulates a type, other than both dealing with r-value references they aren't really related.

Comment: `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(foo)>(foo)` is pretty similar to `std::move(foo)` I suppose.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont This may not hold if `foo` is an lvalue reference: https://godbolt.org/z/o4zP4a. (You would need to remove the reference from the result of `decltype` first: https://godbolt.org/z/Yqno3d.)